# three.js perspectivecamera current angle in degrees

Tags: javascript, three.js, perspectivecamera

For a project I use a PerspectiveCamera which gets rotated using the vrcontrols from r69. At one point I require the current viewing angle degrees (horizontal & vertical degrees at which direction the camera is looking at). How would I acquire those?

Comment: Are you looking for what is normally called "heading" and "pitch" and/or "roll"? If so, the accepted answer is not giving you what you are looking for. Repost if you have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want are also called euler angles. Three.js eulers have a built in function to set them from a quaternion.

```
var quat = new THREE.Quaternion();
var euler = new THREE.Euler();
euler.setFromQuaternion(quat);

alert('X in degrees: ' + euler.x + '\n' +'Y in degrees: ' + euler.y + '\n' + 'Z in degrees: ' + euler.z);
```

Comment: To complete this anwser; the values must then be converted then from radians to degrees, horizontal angle is Z and vertical is X. (So; angleH = THREE.Math.radToDeg(euler.z)).