# Three.js camera.rotation.y to 360 degrees conversion

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to rotate a 2D object (in a GTA style minimap overlay) relevant to the Three.js camera rotation.y value in my 3D scene.

The problem is the radians returned from camera.rotation.y value are a bit strange, going from 0 > -1.4 radians through the first 45 degrees, back from -1.4 > 0 radians through to 90 degrees, 0 > 1.4 radians through to 270 degrees, and 1.4 > 0 radians to 360 degrees.

Does anyone know a way to convert or translate these values into 360 coords?

I'm using PerspectiveCamera and OrbitControls.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting `camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';` and see if the behavior is more intuitive to you. It may run from - PI to + PI, depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley, it turns out that was all it needed! Many thanks (y)

Comment: I posted an answer with further explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be related to converting from quaternion rotations. Not sure if the following example is correct but it might help in you finding the solution.

```js
const euler = new THREE.Euler();
const rotation = euler.setFromQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
const radians = rotation.z > 0
    ? rotation.z
    : (2 * Math.PI) + rotation.z;
const degrees = THREE.Math.radToDeg(radians);
```

This results in `degrees` having a value from 0 to 360 but as the camera rotates the angle values seem to change at an inconsistent rate.

Here's a codepen that demonstrates this behaviour:

http://codepen.io/kevanstannard/pen/NdOvoO/

I used some details from the following question:

[three.js perspectivecamera current angle in degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901618/three-js-perspectivecamera-current-angle-in-degrees)

**Edit #1**

Based on the answer from @WestLangley my answer above is not correct, so just to document the improvement, here's some code based on West's solution:

```js
// Set Y to be the heading of the camera
camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ';
```

And then

```js
const heading = camera.rotation.y;
const radians = heading > 0 ? heading : (2 * Math.PI) + heading;
const degrees = THREE.Math.radToDeg(radians);
```

And a better codepen

http://codepen.io/kevanstannard/pen/YNJgXd

Comment: Thanks for your reply but not quite what I'm after - the issue is the radian values returned from camera.rotation.y, which I explained above - and thus will not convert to a full 0 > 360 degree of range as I pan the camera. 

With the values it returns as I rotate the camera in a full loop (0 > -140 > 0 > 140 > 0 radians) convert to (0 > -90 > 0 > 90 > 0 degrees), not 0 > 360 degrees. 

Can anyone help?

Comment: @DavidTidman sorry, I misread the question. I've revised the answer, hopefully it helps lead you to a solution.

Comment: thank you!! That works perfectly. Now to look at quaternion and eulers to see how that works. Many many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

If you set

```
camera.rotation.order = "YXZ"
```

( the default is "XYZ" ) the Euler angles will make a lot more sense to you:

`rotation.y` will be the camera heading in radians

`rotation.x` will be the camera pitch in radians

`rotation.z` will be the camera roll in radians

The rotations will be applied in that order.

For more information, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517937/three-js-camera-tilt-up-or-down-and-keep-horizon-level/17518092#17518092).

three.js r.84

Answer (score 1):

`camera.rotation` is a so called [Euler angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) as you can also read [here in the three.js docs for `THREE.Object3D`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.rotation) (which is the base class for the `THREE.Camera` class). 
You cannot simply get an angle to a certain axis directly from the euler angle, since the angle you get depends on the order of the euler.